# How to use import statement in one file without modifying package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ecmascript-6, package.json

I wish to use an import statement in a **firebase.js** file
to use the classic import of firebase :

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.11.0/firebase-app.js";
```

The limitations of the project dont allow me to install the firebase npm module

So I try to import it this way instead but I got the error

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

So the only way I know is to add **"type"="module"** to my **package.json** file
but that'll just mess up the entire codebase relying on require, __dirname and other stuff which ecmascript does not support.

So Can I just convert one file type to a module

or is there any other way to import firebase from the url without installing the npm package

Comment: I'm pretty sure that imports in node.js don't allow downloading files from the internet so it won't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to fork [firebase sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) and install it adding to dependencies in package.json:

```
...
"dependencies" : {
    ....
    "firebase": "url_to_your_fork.git",
    ....
}
```

And then do `npm install`.